# Min Path Through Matrix using Dynamic Programming

Tags: java, recursion, matrix, dynamic-programming

I'm working on assignment now for my comp class and am currently getting the hang of dynamic programming. Our current task is that we are given a matrix of size `m x n`, where either m or n is guaranteed to at least be 2. This matrix is filled with various values that dictate how many "steps" we may move from said position in any cardinal direction, with the goal being that we start at index (0,0) and have to make our way to index (n-1,m-1), or, better put, the bottom right corner of the matrix, in the smallest amount of trips as possible. If such a path is not possible, we must return -1. Here's an example:

| 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | 5 |
| 6 | 3 |

The smallest amount of jumps required to get from the top left to the bottom right is 2, since we start at (0,0), which, with value of 1, means we can move 1 step in any direction. We then go to (0,1), which has a value of 2, which we'll use to "step" two positions down into (2,1), which is the bottom right corner. Overall, this journey took two trips: the one from (0,0) to (0,1), and then another from (0,1) to (2,1). It is worth nothing that at position (0,0), I could have also gone down to (0,1), but that wouldn't have resulted in anything useful.

I'm taking a dynamic programming approach, with a table to store previously calculated values and cut down runtime, with a separate table to let me know if I've calculated that position or not. My code is as follows:

```
private static int [][] dpArray;
private static int [][] solveState;
private static int rowDest;
private static int colDest;


public static int min_moves(int[][] board) {
        rowDest = board.length - 1;
        colDest = board[0].length - 1;
        solveState = new int[rowDest + 1][colDest + 1];
        dpArray = new int[rowDest + 1][colDest + 1];
        int ans = minMoveRecur(0,0, board);
        if (ans == 100000000) {
            return -1;
        }

private static int minMoveRecur(int row, int col, int[][] board) {
        if ((row == rowDest) && (col == colDest)) {
            return 0;
        }
        if ((row < 0) || ( rowDest < row) || (col < 0) || (colDest < col)) {
            return 100000000;
        }
        if (solveState[row][col] == 1) {
            return dpArray[row][col];
        }
        solveState[row][col] = 1;
        int up = row - board[row][col];
        int down = row + board[row][col];
        int right = col + board[row][col];
        int left = col - board[row][col];
        int vertBest = Math.min(minMoveRecur(up,col,board),minMoveRecur(down,col,board));
        int horizBest = Math.min(minMoveRecur(row,right,board),minMoveRecur(row,left,board));
        dpArray[row][col] = 1 + Math.min(vertBest,horizBest);
        return dpArray[row][col];
    }
```

I take have a recursive relation that finds which path resulted in the minimum number of jumps, but I have been getting the wrong answer for one of test boards I have, where

```
int [][]board = {{2},{4},{2},{0},{4},{4},{3},{5},{1},{3}};
```

is supposed to take 4 jumps { (0,0) -> (2,0) -> (4,0) -> (8,0) -> (9,0) }, but I keep getting 2 jumps. I've debugged a few times, and it appears that the issue has to do with the `vertBest` and `horizBest` not getting the correct values from the recursive calls. It seems that `vertBest`'s value is always 0, up until the very end where it is 1, which then is added to the 1 from the initial recursive call's `dpArray[row][col] = 1 + Math.min(vertBest,horizBest);` to be 2. It doesn't seem to be adding on the +1 from its earlier calls.

Can anyone help shed some light on what's going wrong here?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but have you considered a modified version of [Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)? It wouldn't be difficult to implement (in my opinion, easier than debugging this custom algorithm) and is worthwhile to learn for your future coursework.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to go up, in the `minMoveRecur(up,col,board)` call, `solveState[row][col] = 1` however you have not updated `dpArray[row][col]` yet.

As a result since `solveState[row][col] = 1` and `dpArray[row][col]`, 0  is returned (due to the 3rd if condition) and 1 is added to it.